# How do i access the context data in the template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

```
    context_object_name = 'item_list'
    template_name = 'krop_view.html'
    model = Item

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user  #gets current user object
        krop = get_object_or_404(Krop, owner=user)
        return Item.objects.filter(krop=krop)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(KropListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user 
        context['krop'] = Krop.objects.filter(owner=user)
        return context
```

A "Krop" is technically a shop with items, i can get all items for the shop owned by the current user. I want to also access data from the Krop model so I passed in the krop context data related to current user. How do I access this context data in the template? I've tried and looked up ways to get the specific variables like:

{{ krop.owner }}
  {{ item_list.krop.owner }}

ultimetley I want to access data from two different tables, but for one page. Please and thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your krop variable is a queryset with multiple items. You need to loop through them and you will be able to access the fields that you want.

```
{% for item in krop %}
    Owner: {{ item.owner }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now say if i only wanted to access and display one object from the list?

Comment: Which one in particular? You want krop to be only one object? If you are sure that filtering by owner only returns one result you can use '.get' instead of '.filter'. But take into account that if there is no match, using 'get' will throw an error.

Comment: I now have the view set up so i only get the filter list if Items, but each Item object has an owner, not the current user, but the name of their Krop and i want to display that only once at top of page then proceed to list all the items.

Comment: I figured it out just changing up my get_context_data method a little bit instead, thanks for your help!